# Read an XML document and removing nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file, similar to the one below.  I will read the XML and find the EmpId node.  Based on other data will determine if I need to keep this node or delete the node.  Currently have a process which reads it and creates a list of Record Ids which I will need to remove.   In the below XML I will want to keep the EmpId = Emp1 and remove EmpId = Emp2.  The removal is the  node.

I believe the best approach is to read the XML first to determine which nodes to keep and then go thru the XML again and remove the necessary nodes.

What's the best approach to remove these nodes?
I'm open to creating a new XML document and creating the node which need to be kept.   Based on the data I'm reading it's 50/50 if I'll be removing more nodes or keeping more nodes.

```
...
<HeaderNode>
  <Details>
    <SubmissionId>1</SubmissionId>
    <EmpDetail>
      <RecordId>1</RecordId>
      <EmpDempgraphic>
        <EmpId>Emp1</EmpId>
      </EmpDempgraphic>
    </EmpDetail>
    <EmpDetail>
      <RecordId>2</RecordId>
      <EmpDempgraphic>
        <EmpId>Emp2</EmpId>
      </EmpDempgraphic>
    </EmpDetail>
  </Details>
</HeaderNode>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace XML
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement EmpDetail = doc.Descendants("EmpDetail").Where(x => (int)x.Element("RecordId") == 2).FirstOrDefault();

            EmpDetail.Remove();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the document is huge, just load it into an [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8), [Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove?view=netframework-4.8) the elements you don't want, and [Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save?view=netframework-4.8) the document back out.